# How to store specific key item in a variable from PHP array?

Tags: php

I've looked through several SO posts and cannot get this simple PHP function to work.  I have a variable `$is_a_member` set to the following:

```
array ( 'user_id' => '3', 'group_id' => '7', )
```

All I'm trying to do is simply store the `group_id` as a separate variable.

I've tried `$is_a_member['group_id']` and `array_column` based on other's posts, but I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I believe the trailing comma is what is causing the issue, but this data is received from another system. Any ideas on how I could remove that comma?

Comment: Any error you r getting??

Comment: `$groupId = $is_a_member['group_id'];` Pretty simple, so what's the actually issue?

Comment: I agree, it should be simple, but when I run the page, it's just blank, and I know it's related to this function. I'm trying to get errors outputted.

Comment: Comman is no problem: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76837a2cac4196d2c06e5be21e05c345e70b885e

Comment: It is when you store it as another variable and try to use it: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e60e38bfced38f1425302ffc709a613d8af1895

Comment: `Having a trailing comma after the last defined array entry, while unusual, is a valid syntax.` copy directly from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php, i believe your issue lies somewhere else

Comment: It would have been better if you posted the relevant code in your question. Without it we'll be just guessing.

Comment: You are using `echo = $b` in your sandbox link, and `echo` doesn't mix well with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array ( 'user_id' => '3', 'group_id' => '7',);                                                   

echo $a['group_id'];//echoes 7
```

see [demo here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b73b9f38183a5d58d1035fb7cac771b39fe8698)